# How do I enable logging for Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: java, javascript, google-closure-compiler

[Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) has this flag for logging:

```
--logging_level VAL
    The logging level (standard java.util.logging.Level values)
    for Compiler progress. Does not control errors or warnings
    for the JavaScript code under compilation.
```

So I can set the logging level to one of: `SEVERE`, `WARNING`, `INFO`, `CONFIG`, `FINE`, `FINER`, `FINEST`.

But how do I enable logging, and where is the log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called `logging.properties` with the following contents:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern   = closure-compiler.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Then set the `java.util.logging.config.file` Java system property to `logging.properties` when running the application:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties \
     -jar compiler.jar \
     --js script.js \
     --logging_level FINEST
```

The log will be written to `closure-compiler.log`.